# parse rows by ID from csv

Tags: ruby

How can you parse rows by id in to an array?

example:

```
id  | name |  descritption
---------------------------
1   | eg1  | dummytext1
1   | eg2  | dummytext2
2   | eg3  | dummytext3
2   | eg4  | dummytext4
```

example question, how could i parse the rows with the id of 2 in to an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
result = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = Hash.new { |j,l| j[l] = [] } }

FasterCSV.foreach( "yourfile.csv", :headers=>true, :header_converters=>:symbol ) do |line|
  if line[:id] == 2
    result[:id][:name] << line[:name]
    result[:id][:descritption] << line[:descritption]
  end
end
```

Take note that this code is untested.

The documentation about CSV library is [here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html)

Comment: This works great but others that might want to note that fastercsv is now standard library and there's no need to declare it as FasterCSV, CSV works fine.. thank you